# Broken images in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I have a small problem. There are 2 language pictures from master page. Although it works everywhere but it does not work on the detail page. This code for page link
DetailPage;

```
<div class="view-all"><a href="<%# string.Format("/{0}/{1}", Eval("NewsId").ToString(),Createcode(Eval("NewsName").ToString())) %>">Read more...</a></div>
```

And I am using Global.asax for it;

```
 public void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("", "{NewsId}/{NewsName}", "~/NewsDetail.aspx");
        }
```

Why pictures are broken? How can I fix them?

Comment: You need to post the html source code of detail page where the pictures are not working. Most probably its relative path issue, since your this detail page URL is one directory deep.

Comment: The URL to your image is incorrect.

Comment: But it works every pages except detail. If it is incorrect, It did not appear anywhere

Comment: 1 up-vote for your post